# Microsoft Expression Blend 3 - Show / Hide a popup

Tags: expression-blend, show-hide, expression-sketchflow

I'm using this for the very first time to do some quick prototyping (using sketchflow). I have a simple dialog window that I want to show when a button it pressed and then hide when a button (in the dialog, like an "OK" button) is pressed. If someone could just point me in the direction of a simple tutorial on how to do this I'd be happy, or even if you have a simple example you can post here that would be great (I've been trying to google this forever!).

I can tell you what I have tried (although obviously it doesn't work)

1. Created a user control, called it "MyDialog". That user control is a simple box which is the bit of gui I want to overlay when the user clicks a button.
2. In that user control I gave it two states "Show" and "Hide". The "Hide" state has all visability to the elements in this user control set to none and "Show" shows everything
3. Created a button in my main screen. That button I gave a it a behaviour "ActivateStateAction". In the properties of that behaviour I set the TargetScreen to be "MyDialog" and the TargetState to be "Show". (I also set the target screen to be MyprojectName.MyProjectNameScreens.MyDialog, that doesn't work either)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the behaviour I was using. I used "GoToStateAction" (not sure why I missed it before) and the approach above and it all works.

Comment: How did you target the original screen when using "GoToStateAction"?